# Python3.8 cannot install shap, llvmlite, or numba

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip, llvm

I'm trying to install snap:

`sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install shap`

but this produces

```
  Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
  Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
  C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC
  
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/numba
  compile options: '-I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numba/_dynfuncmod.c
  In file included from numba/_dynfunc.c:6:0,
                   from numba/_dynfuncmod.c:1:
  numba/_pymodule.h:6:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c numba/_dynfuncmod.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/numba/_dynfuncmod.o" failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for numba
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for llvmlite ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpeqdilkydpip-wheel- --python-tag cp38:
  running bdist_wheel
  /usr/bin/python3.8 /tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
  LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 105, in main_posix
      out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 191, in <module>
      main()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 181, in main
      main_posix('linux', '.so')
    File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 107, in main_posix
      raise RuntimeError("%s failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG "
  RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
  error: command '/usr/bin/python3.8' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build shap numba llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba, python-dateutil, pandas, slicer, tqdm, shap
  Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o_ke5g0q-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.35.0', 'full': 'ea23b026930cc00824c907172383f54c9d438e6b'}
    running build_ext
    /usr/bin/python3.8 /tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 105, in main_posix
        out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 181, in main
        main_posix('linux', '.so')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 107, in main_posix
        raise RuntimeError("%s failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG "
    RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
    error: command '/usr/bin/python3.8' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o_ke5g0q-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g2j9vqik/llvmlite/
```

I'm getting similar errors with `numba` and `llvm`

when I have errors like this with CPAN, there is usually a suggestion to install an Ubuntu package like `sudo apt install somepackage` but I don't see anything like that in the error message.

From what I can tell, I'm using the latest version of `pip`:

```
con@V:~/Scripts/python3$ sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (21.0.1)
```

how can I alter my system to install `shap`?

Comment: `Python.h` is part of `libpython3-dev` in Ubuntu.

Comment: my system says `libpython3-dev is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).`

Comment: Your `libpython3-dev` is for Python 3.6, and you ran `python3.8 -m pip`.

Comment: @phd I've installed `libpython3.8-dev` and `llvm-9-dev` but `shap` installation still fails an install with similar error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was that with so many libraries with so many different potentially incompatible versions around, it was a complete mess.

The solution:

1. `sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools`
2. `sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install colorama --upgrade`
3. `sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install shap`

the reason that this solution wasn't so obvious is because none of this was mentioned in the error messages.